# Adding click event for a button created dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to add a button click event on a button that was added dynamically using jQuery?

The jQuery code that adds the dynamic buttons inside a `div` container:

```
$('#pg_menu_content').empty();
$div = $('<div data-role="fieldcontain"/>');
$("<input type='button' value='Dynamic Button' id='btn_a' />").appendTo($div.clone()).appendTo('#pg_menu_content');
```

**Question 1:**
How can I add a click event for the above button?  I tried the below and it has not triggered

```
$("#btn_a").click(function(){
  alert ('button clicked');
});
```

**Question 2:**
How can I get the value of the button inside the click event?  For example I want to get the value 'Dynamic Button' inside the click event function.

Can you guys please help me on this.

Comment: Either bind the event after the element is appended or delegate it to its parent that exists in DOM always.

Comment: This video helped me - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unk-U_LQWuA

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler bound to the container:

```
$('#pg_menu_content').on('click', '#btn_a', function(){
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

That is, bind to an element that exists at the moment that the JS runs (I'm assuming `#pg_menu_content` exists when the page loads), and supply a selector in the second parameter to `.on()`. When a click occurs on `#pg_menu_content` element jQuery checks whether it applied to a child of that element which matches the `#btn_a` selector.

Either that or bind a standard (non-delegated) click handler after creating the button.

Either way, within the click handler `this` will refer to the button in question, so `this.value` will give you its value.

Comment: It looks like this will cause the handler to fire twice if the element already exists.

Comment: @JihoKang - No it doesn't. Why would it? There's only one handler.

Comment: `this` is a raw DOM element so needs re-wrapping for jquery functionality, ie, `$(this)`

Answer (score 29):

Use

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn_a", function(){
  alert ('button clicked');
});
```

to add the listener for the dynamically created button.

```
alert($("#btn_a").val());
```

will give you the value of the button

Answer (score 13):

Just create a button element with jQuery, and add the event handler when you create it :

```
var div = $('<div />', {'data-role' : 'fieldcontain'}),
    btn = $('<input />', {
              type  : 'button',
              value : 'Dynamic Button',
              id    : 'btn_a',
              on    : {
                 click: function() {
                     alert ( this.value );
                 }
              }
          });

div.append(btn).appendTo( $('#pg_menu_content').empty() );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JuBAz/)

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**: Use `.delegate` on the div to bind a click handler to the button.

**Question 2**: Use `$(this).val()` or `this.value` (the latter would be faster) inside of the click handler.  `this` will refer to the button.

```
$("#pg_menu_content").on('click', '#btn_a', function () {
  alert($(this).val());
});

$div = $('<div data-role="fieldcontain"/>');
$("<input type='button' value='Dynamic Button' id='btn_a' />").appendTo($div.clone()).appendTo('#pg_menu_content');
```