# How to write script tag inside build html in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying open build html(inside js funtion) to show table on a new tab.
Now I am trying to add a js function for user to download table in excel format, but as soon as I try to add  tag code breaks.

I tried following:
Wrote download funtion inside script tag of built html code in js function.
Added a new javascript file containing download js function.
Added download function in a variable and tried including it in script tag.
Used <script> instead of  tag.

Following are my code:

```
var myfunction = function download() {
            $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var data_type = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel";
                var table_div = document.getElementById("table_wrapper");
                var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, "%20");

                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = data_type + ", " + table_html;
                a.download = "exported_table_" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 1000000) + ".xls";
                a.click();
            });
        };

        var html='<html><head><title>Locale Value</title><script>'+myfunction+'</script></head>'+
        '<body><h2>'+Header+'</h2><br><br><table>  <tr>    <th>Key</th>    <th>Value</th></tr>';

        for (var key in data) {
            var eachrow = '<tr>'
            + '<td>' + key + '</td>'
            + '<td>' + data[key] + '</td>'
            + '</tr>';
            html=html+eachrow;
        }
        html=html+'</table><br><br><button id="exportExcel" onclick="download()">Export</button></body></html>';
        return html;
    }
```

The problem here is as soon as I close script tag(i.e ),
my main script tag (in which all functions are written) is shown as closed. And same appears on screen.

Comment: Have you tried `onclick="myFunction()"`? Also this is not the correct way to do. Use `document.createElement('button')` to create button and then use `button.addEventListener` to add handler to it. Alternatively you can even do `$("#exportExcel").on('click', myFunction)`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253246/adding-click-event-for-a-button-created-dynamically-using-jquery

Comment: As soon as I write 
<script>'+myfunction+'</script>
my code breaks.
How do I include download function in my new html code ?

Comment: I have updated your code check below ans here was the problem : + **myfunction +'</' + 'script></head>'**

Answer (score 0):

use "\" in a string. the symbol "\<" is an escape character for "<".

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code please check :

```js
   $(function () {
    var myfunction = function download() {
        $("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var data_type = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel";
            var table_div = document.getElementById("table_wrapper");
            var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, "%20");

            var a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = data_type + ", " + table_html;
            a.download = "exported_table_" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 1000000) + ".xls";
            a.click();
        });

    var html = '<html><head><title>Locale Value</title><script>' + myfunction + '</' + 'script></head>' +
    '<body><h2>' + Header + '</h2><br><br><table>  <tr>    <th>Key</th>    <th>Value</th></tr>';

    for (var key in data) {
        var eachrow = '<tr>'
        + '<td>' + key + '</td>'
        + '<td>' + data[key] + '</td>'
        + '</tr>';
        html = html + eachrow;
    }
    html = html + '</table><br><br><button id="exportExcel" onclick="download()">Export</button></body></html>';
    return html;
  };
});
```

Comment: Screen is coming blank, after looking into console it says:
Invalid or unexpected token

js code is showing as 
html=html+'</table><br><br><button id="exportExcel" onclick="download()">Export</button></div>

even though my code is 
html=html+'</table><br><br><button id="exportExcel" onclick="download()">Export</button></body></html>';

Comment: I have updated my code plz copy and paste then it will work