# How to use jQuery to add event to static d3 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to add click event to a d3 circle element that is static. I dynamically loaded this d3 code:

```
     var svgContainer = d3.select("#vis").append("svg")
                                .attr("width", 200)
                                .attr("height", 200);

    //Draw the Circle
      var circle = svgContainer.append("circle")
                    .attr("class","item")
                    .attr("cx", 30)
                    .attr("cy", 30)
                    .attr("r", 20);
```

Somewhere in my code, I want to add the click event to circles that contain a class called "item".  I am using following code but it does not work

```
  $('.item').on('click', function(){
     console.log("click added");
  });
```

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253246/adding-click-event-for-a-button-created-dynamically-using-jquery) as well but it did not help me.

Comment: Is the click event listener added after the d3 code draws the circles? P.S. d3.js as its own event listening system, you may use it rather than jQuery.

Comment: Thanks. I was calling it before loading the d3 code.