# I want to show modal popup before leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, model-view-controller

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h" id="leave">click here to leave the page</a>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Changes made may not be saved.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

$("#leave").click(function() {
  $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Changes you made may not be Saved';
  });
});
```

[here is the js fiddle am working on](https://jsfiddle.net/vishagvj/qkbgzyhc/74/)

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Closest you will get methinks is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253246/adding-click-event-for-a-button-created-dynamically-using-jquery. OR Just make you check if a 'saved' variable is set.

Comment: could you please confirm if you need that "beforeunload" event or it is just for example? if you don't need it then it's possible to show model otherwise not.

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent the `leave` link's default behavior, display the dialog and use timeout to redirect the page in a few seconds.

Example:

```
$("#leave").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = this.href;
  //code to show dialog
  window.setTimeout(function() {    
    window.location.href = link;
  }, 2000);
});
```

Also, you need to wrap the script codes in a `script` html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you set up redirecting logic inside the modal button and let the `a` element display the modal.It seems like a simpler solution.

```js
$("#leave").click(e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#myModal").modal({
        show: true
    })
})
$("#proceedLeaveBtn").click(() => {
    window.location.href = "https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h"
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="leave">click here to leave the page</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Changes made may not be saved.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button id="proceedLeaveBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Proceed</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

You can even specify `data-href` attribute inside the button element and retrive it  inside the click handler.Its up to you.